# How do I change the port number in Udacity GAE project?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, maven-plugin

In the [Udacity Developing Scalable Apps with Java course](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud859/l-1215898636/m-1453109037), I imported the [Hello Endpoints project](https://github.com/udacity/ud859) and tried to run it on Eclipse EE as instructed. However I got the following error message:

```
[INFO] ***********************************************************
[INFO] Could not open the requested socket: Address already in use
[INFO] Try overriding --address and/or --port.
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.954 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-14T10:03:16-02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/221M
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I change the port number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are building a Maven project, you can edit the `pom.xml` file and uncomment the `<port>8080</port>` value and set it to an unused port.